# What is preventing this piece of code to run when onEdit() is performed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a piece of code that syncronize two sheets (the motivation behind it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444102/google-apps-script-is-there-a-way-to-keep-two-sheets-synchronized/20459220?noredirect=1#comment30573552_20459220)). I got this code from a SOF previous answer:

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = SPREADSHEET.getId();
var sourceWorksheetName = "myData";
var destinationSpreadsheetID = "0AmEr9uNtZwnNdDFKMTVlbmZYZ3ZyOWM0aXpZS2twM1Z";
var destinationWorksheetName = "myData2";

function importData() {
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
  var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
  var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();
  var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetID);
  var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinationWorksheetName);
  var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(),thisData.getNumColumns());
  toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues());
}

function onEdit(){
  importData();
}
```

But when I open the sheet and edit it, nothing happens. Why?

PS - As I pointed before, I've already ask a similar question. But I think this is another question, because I'm not looking for the same answer from the previous question (How to make 2 sheets sync?) but a more specific question: what is preventing this code -- this solution -- of work?

Comment: Where's the global `SPREADSHEET` coming from?

Comment: You've got a function named `onChange()`, but you don't mention whether or not you've installed it as a Spreadsheet Change Trigger. You need to do that, or it won't run.

Comment: Hi, @BryanP, the global `SPREADSHEET` is defined in my code.
Yes, onChange(), is suppose to be a spreadsheet trigger.
I also tried the onEdit() trigger and it didn't work.

Comment: I was curious how it is defined b/c I'm seeing experiencing [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3464) which I thought may be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a complement to the other answers, here are a few explanations :

In the [documentation about spreadsheet triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_container_triggers?hl=fr-FR) you will find all the details about what [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR#Simple) can do (and can not do) and how to setup the so called "[installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers?hl=fr-FR#ActionTriggers)".

The simple triggers run automatically without asking anything to the user modifying the spreadsheet and run as this "active user". For this reason, they can't do anything that requires authorization.

The installable triggers execute under the authority of the author of the script, in other words the person who created the trigger, and they need to be explicitly authorized by the script author.  This also means that these function will access the script author data and **not** the user data.

A simple example : if a function triggered by an installable trigger sends an email, this email will be sent by the script author, not by the spreadsheet user... that's quite a difference.

What might have bring some confusion to you in the example you are showing is that the `onEdit` function does nothing else than calling another function... but if you look at it more thoroughly, the `importData` function is calling spreadsheet function and thus requires authorizations for spreadsheet access.

That's definitely why your onEdit does nothing.(please note that it is failing *silently*... another confusing detail :-)

Hoping this explanation will make it clearer.

Comment: As always, the most clear answer, thanks. Yes, my doubt was this: "What might have bring some confusion to you in the example you are showing is that the onEdit function does nothing else than calling another function... but if you look at it more thoroughly, the importData function is calling spreadsheet function and thus requires authorizations for spreadsheet access." Google should show a error msg when this happens.

Comment: I followed the instructions to installed triggers and now it works like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the help for onEdit. In there it says it cant do many things. Instead install your own trigger like onMyEdit

Answer (score 0):

Your function name onChange() suggests you may be using the wrong trigger type.

onEdit() and onChange() are triggered by different circumstances and the situation you describe means that you want onEdit()

Also as the commenter above states you will need to change the first line to the following to avoid returning 'undefined':

var sourceSpreadsheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();